# Automatically sorting a range of cells after one cell within the range has been modified?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, spreadsheet

I have a number of named vertical ranges on a spreadsheet, containing lists of names. New names are usually manually added at the very end of each list. Obviously, this means that unless manually sorted, the lists will not be in alphabetical order. Is there any way, via a macro if needed, to have each range automatically sort itself once any of its component cells has been modified? The idea would be to have each list/range alphabetically sorted immediately after a given user adds a new name to it.

I haven't delved much into VBA for Excel nor with automating its sorting functionality, so forgive my ignorance if the answer is a bit too obvious.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You'll need to act on worksheet change events. Give it a shot and let us know if you become stuck.

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a shot. Will post here if I get stuck or manage to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I did it. Like Raystafarian suggested, I handled the `Worksheet_Change` event and used the `Range().Sort` function to get my columns ordered. Each column has a header and I wanted them ordered alphabetically in ascending order, so here's my function:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Range("A2:A100").Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    Range("B2:B100").Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    Range("C2:C100").Sort Key1:=Range("C1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    Range("D2:D100").Sort Key1:=Range("D1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    Range("E2:E100").Sort Key1:=Range("E1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    Range("F2:F100").Sort Key1:=Range("F1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Might not be a particularly elegant or foolproof solution, but it solves my problem perfectly and with a bit of training, users will know not to modify the header columns.

Thanks, Raystafarian!